# Is there any way to simulate or change blocks production of a developers aeternity node?

Tags: smartcontracts, aeternity-blockchain

I'm looking to improve the time it takes me to test my smart contract logic. It's painful to be waiting for blocks to confirm but even harder to simulate reverts. Is there any way to make this better?

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is. You can use[devmode](https://github.com/aeternity/aeplugin_dev_mode) which allows you to control how blocks are produced in your node. You will be also able to discard by doing rollback to a specific block number.